# How can I split my Screen in two parts which can be switched by pulling up or down. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

For example in Google Maps it looks like this:

[Google Maps first View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnmOM.jpg)

[image: Google Maps second View]

Comment: You're probably looking for [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html). There are alternatives but you can start with this.

Comment: This i actually a [ModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html). Check it out. You can adjust it for your own desire.